# How can I setFriend with using of useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do some small exercises in react, but here I got some error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Could anyone help me, please?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import FriendProfile from './FriendProfile';
import Button from './Button';

const Friend = () => {
    const [friend, setFriend] = useState({})
    async function getFriend() {
        try{
            const response = await fetch('https://www.randomuser.me/api?results=1')
            const data = await response.json()
            const [item] = data.results;
             setFriend(item)

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

    }


useEffect(() => {
    getFriend()
}, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Button getFriend={getFriend} />
            <FriendProfile />

        </div>
    );
};

export default Friend;
```

and FriendProfile component is:

```
import React from 'react';

const FriendProfile = ({friend})  => {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li>{friend.name.first}</li>
        </ul>
    );
};

export default FriendProfile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass to `<FriendProfile />` component the `friend` object. In the child component it tries to destructure like `({friend})` but there is no value there. That's why you are getting that error message.

Try to pass as the following:

```
<FriendProfile friend={friend} />
```

Then in the `<FriendProfile>` component you need to do the additional conditional rendering:

```
<ul>
    {
        friend.name &&
        <li>{friend.name.first}</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Technically we are checking if `friend.name` has value or not. Once the API call returned and updated the state, it will render the `<li>` element with the first name of the `friend` object.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ja i forget to add here in the post but on my code is there but still have problem

Comment: @razmo Just updated my answer, figured out there was another error as well. Let me know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: wow ...That works perfectly, but why? could you explain that?  and if I want to render the last name and another detail should i do the same?

Comment: @razmo I guess if you need that, you need something like this: `{ friend.name &&    <li>{friend.name.first} - {friend.name.last}</li> }`. I hope this works for you. Just added further explanation in my answer. If the solution works for you, please consider upvoting and accepting as the answer for the question. Thank you!